# Convertir Procedure en LinQ

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, linq

como puedo convertir este procedure en linQ, estoy aprendiendo y quisiera un ejemplo de como convertirlo y poder guiarme para poder empezar a practicar por mi cuenta , estuve buscando ejemplos pero solo dan lo básico , este procedure maneja joins y y tiene 2 entradas , quiero pasarlo a ASP.NET Core

**este es el procedimiento**

```
USE [SVMQAS]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ugv_sp_pin_validation]    Script Date: 10/12/2020 11:57:59 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[ugv_sp_pin_validation] 
@IMEI varchar(25),
@PIN varchar(15)

as
BEGIN
  -- date: 31/07/2020
  declare @cod_persona varchar(110)
  declare @es_reparto bit = 0

    select @cod_persona = p.cod_persona
    from afcma_persona p
      join afcma_vendedor v on v.cod_vendedor = p.cod_persona
    where p.IMEI = @IMEI and p.cod_clave=@PIN

  if @cod_persona is null
    begin
      select @cod_persona = cod_persona, @es_reparto = 1
      from afcma_persona
      where imei2 = @IMEI and cod_clave=@PIN
    end

    select p.cod_persona,
           p.cod_tipo_persona,
           iif(@es_reparto = 0, p.dsc_razon_social, concat('REPARTO DE ', p.dsc_razon_social)) dsc_razon_social,
           p.dsc_nombre_comercial,
           p.num_ruc,
           p.num_doc_identidad,
           p.flg_afecto_percepcion,
           p.cod_clave,
           p.IMEI,
           p.PERNR,
           p.fch_ultima_venta,
           p.imp_ultima_venta,
           iif(@es_reparto = 1, cast(1 as bit), v.iti_reparto) iti_reparto,
           iif(@es_reparto = 1, cast(0 as bit), v.iti_preventista) iti_preventista,
           p.cod_repartidor,
           p.imei2
    from afcma_persona p
      join afcma_vendedor v on v.cod_vendedor = p.cod_persona
    where p.cod_persona = @cod_persona

END
```

Comment: Deberias poner lo que has intentado y no pasarle tu problema que otro te lo resuelva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese procedimiento tiene 3 consultas select, deberias hacer los mismos pasos.

Para desglosar la consulta y entiendas, es asi:

1: `from persona in "tabla BD` -> "persona es tu variable interna de la consulta"

2: `join vendedor ->"segunda variable interna de otra tabla" in "tabla BD" on vendedor.cod_vendedor equals persona.cod_persona` (en esta linea tenes que llamar en este orden a las tablas porque notaras que si lo haces al reves el intellisense no te dectara las variables internas.

3: notaras que te envolvi la consulta entre ( ) y le ejecuto un metodo, para que traiga un solo registro. Si son muchos podrías hacer `().ToList()`. Sino le sacas los parentesis y luego ejecutas la consulta en un `foreach`

```
 private Persona ObtenerPersona(int _Imei)
 {
  var persona = (from person in db.afcma_persona
                join vendedor in afcma_vendedor on p.cod_vendedor equals person.cod_person
                where person.Imei == _Imei
                select person).FirstOrDefault();
     if(persona != null)
     {
       //rellenas tu objeto persona
       return new Persona()
                  {
                   cod_persona = persona.cod_Persona;
                  }
     }
     return persona;
  }
```

Segunda opcion para ejecutar la misma consulta.

```
  var persona = from person in db.afcma_persona
                join vendedor in afcma_vendedor on p.cod_vendedor equals person.cod_person
                where person.Imei == "TuVariable"
                select person;


 foreach(var item in persona)
 {

 }
```